# Eclipse Ganymede HTML editor incredibly slow when editing attributes

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-3.4

I recently upgraded to Eclipse Ganymede from Europa and now I'm finding that when I'm editing JSP files the IDE crawls when editing HTML attributes (but not JSP attributes).

Has anyone experienced this, or have any suggestions?

Also if you can point me to a better place to ask Eclipse related questions, do tell.

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you using ?

Comment: I've found editing *anything* in Eclipse to be incredibly slow. Sometimes, even with Eclipse the only program running, there will be a 5-second delay between typing a character and that character showing up on screen...in the default text editor... This horrible performance has been a stable of Eclipse for nearly 10 years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The visual editors in Eclipse are slow. I have no idea why that is; other graphics frameworks achieve mindboggling effects in Java in real time so they shouldn't be that slow.

I suggest you open a bug report against Eclipse. This way, you can give them feedback and see what they think about it plus you can track any progress if they accept it.

As for asking Eclipse questions, [go to the newsgroups](http://www.eclipse.org/newsgroups/). There are also mailing lists but those are only for developers working *on* Eclipse (not those who work *with* it). So they are only an option should you choose to work on this bug :)

Comment: Also, Eclipse's SWT is implemented very differently on different platforms (and sometimes within the same platform).

Comment: It's been 2 years since this question was answered, and Eclipse is still slow.

Comment: In Eclipse JUNO, Still this problem persist. Even sometime when we press CTRL key, it hangs.

Comment: Well, a lot of people complain about the performance but no one cares enough to scratch that itch, so it's probably not important enough to fix (-> if it was, someone would have fixed it).

Answer (score 7):

For Eclipse Ganymede: You can use the following menu to disable HTML validation all together or parts of it by project.

Right Click on the project | Project Properties | Validation | Enable Project Specific Settings.

Then you can disable HTML Validation.

Or, from Project Properties, click open Validation and select HTML Validation.  Select Enable Project Specific Settings and set any of the ten element checks to "Ignore."

You can also turn these settings off for the entire workspace using the Windows (Eclipse) Preferences | Validation settings.

Answer (score 5):

The problem still persist today, as it seem.
I know the problem, but I don't know yet how to counter it...

You can see that if you try to edit an attribute at the *end of the document*, it is not as slow as editing an attribute at the *beginning of the document*.

Or you may see that if you try to edit attributes that have their ending-quote already in place (for example, first type in: `attribute_name=""` and only then type in the attribute value, it is also not slow.

The problem occurs because when you type in an attribute without a value-ending quote ("), like so: `attribute_name="...`, the rest of the document becomes the value of that attribute and is being processed by eclipse for every keystroke you make.

I have spent about half an hour looking at how to disable attribute value processing but failed (maybe I didn't look for it long enough).

Ben

Answer (score 3):

Try closing the overview tab

Comment: This is the only thing that helped for me!  I'm using Juno to edit JSP

Answer (score 2):

untick Enable folding in Preferences > General > Editors > Structured Text Editors

Answer (score 0):

Using the eclipse update site I had previously installed Eclipse Web Developer Tools.
It seems something included in this makes the JSP editor extremely slow.

I un-installed this and installed the Web Page Editor which also includes the JSP editor and does not have the same slow issue

Answer (score 0):

Here they say **Eclipse Kepler** will overcome this issue: [Is Eclipse Too Slow Switching Tabs?](http://softwareprole.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/is-eclipse-too-slow-switching-tabs/). Unfortunately patch link for Eclipse Juno is now broken... so I'll wait for Kepler.

Answer (score -1):

```
Project > Properties > JavaScript > Include Path > Source
```

Delete dir with tons of **js** files, such as JQuery, etc...
Eclipse gets lost with too many **source code** to **compile**.

Comment: How is deleting the code you're working with a solution for a slow IDE?